# Kotlin DAO with Exposed: How to reduce redundancy in classes?

Tags: object-oriented, sql, kotlin

I'm writing a Kotlin app that uses Exposed (https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) as a SQL wrapper to write and read objects from databases. The problem I'm facing is that I end up with 3 classes featuring the same variables. For example:

```
package database

import hashLength
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntityClass
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntIdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table

object LogEntries : IntIdTable() {
    val logId = binary("id", hashLength).primaryKey()
    val prev = binary("prev", hashLength).index()
    val owner = varchar("owner", 32).index()
    val timestamp = long("timestamp").index()
    val action = integer("action")
    val proof = text("proof")
    val nonce = binary("nonce", 8)
    val signature = binary("signature", 32)
}

class LogEntry(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<LogEntry>(LogEntries)

    var logId by LogEntries.logId
    var prev by LogEntries.prev
    var owner by LogEntries.owner
    var timestamp by LogEntries.timestamp
    var action by LogEntries.action
    var proof by LogEntries.proof
    var nonce by LogEntries.nonce
    var signature by LogEntries.signature
}

data class LogEntryHolder(
    var logId: ByteArray,
    val prev: ByteArray,
    val owner: String,
    val timestamp: Long,
    val action: Int,
    val proof: String,
    val nonce: ByteArray,
    val signature: ByteArray
)
```

The first is the Exposed DAO class (I don't use that directly), the second is a wrapper (companion class) to where I add more functions, this is where I do my CRUD operations on. The third is an in-memory class that I use to 'create' the object before storing it in the database. There are 2 reasons for that:

1: I now can edit the object before persisting it in the database (otherwise if I create a new `LogEntry` it's immediately saved in the database and I have to edit the log again directly after storing it, which seems counter-intuitive.

2: When processing through a function, I just have to supply the `LogEntryHolder` instead of passing all the values of the object individually.

Is there are way to reduce the amount of classes needed, so that the final code is less error-prone and redundant? Thanks a lot!